# How to apply indexes for searching

Tags: python, django, indexing, django-models

There a lot of objects in DB so searching in Admin is extremely slow.
I have these models defined:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)

class LogEmail(models.Model):
    log = models.ForeignKey(Log)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=350, db_index=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey('sites.Site')
```

and here's my ModelAdmin:

```
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('logemail__email',)
```

So, I have index for email field in LogEmail and I guess FK indexes are created by default. How can I speed this thing up? I tried adding `index_together`, like:

```
class LogEmail(models.Model):
    log = models.ForeignKey(Log)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=350, db_index=True)
    site = models.ForeignKey('sites.Site')

    class Meta:
        index_together = (
            ('log', 'email'),
        )
```

But I didn't notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a similar issue with my site, and I made it faster by annotating the queryset with the related object to avoid making a query for each object.

```
from django.db.models import F

class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('email',)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ShipmentAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(email=F('logemail__email'))

    def email(self, obj):
        return obj.email
    email.short_description = "Email"
```

This adds the `JOIN` clause in the query and should help speed up the search.